# Moving baby stroller on loose dirt on shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, contemporary-halacha, grama

According to Halacha, is there any issue with pushing a baby stroller over loose dirt on Shabbat?  What if you don’t need the dirt and this is only going to happen anyway? Would this be any issue of Choresh or any other type of melacha?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if this case is different from any other psik reisha?

Comment: related (duplicate?): [Pushing a buggy on grass on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114911/11501)